# How to make the listbox rows not able to be selected?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml

[image]

The image above depicts a ListBox. You can see the rows are able to be selected. However they should be not selectable when i click on the row, but i have no idea on how to solve this problem.
My question is, how to make the listbox rows above not able to be selected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to use an [ItemsControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) instead of a ListBox. It's a similar control that doesn't allow selection.

Answer (score 0):

You can retemplate the control, removing the selected state animation.  Easy to do if you have Blend.

Right click on the ListBox, select Edit Additional Templates | Edit Generated Item Container | Edit A Copy.  Switch to the States tab and choose the Selected state.  (For Silverlight) you should see that the Rectangle "fillColor2" has a red circle, showing it's Opacity property is animated in this state.  Expand fillColor2, click Opacity, and press delete.  You can also do the same for the Focused state (and MouseOver state, if you don't want a mouseover effect)